# Baking massive materials into one texture

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I am trying to bake massive materials of 10,812 buildings into one texture. Individual buildings uniquely are designed and modeled. The purpose is to visulize a meteorological simulation data at a local distict in mega city. I've succeeded in baking 1,728 materials into one texture, and it took 3 days to run smart uv projection. But the massive materials seem to require longer than 1 month to run smart uv projection. So it would be good if there is a parallel way to project the massive materials. Or if another smart way exits, it would be appreciated.

[image]
*massive materials of buildings*

[image]
*1,728 materials baked into one material*

As a rule of thumb, I divided the massive materials into 4 neighborhoods and applied smart uv projection to each mesh. And I baked each material into one.
But I found no fast way to combine the 4 uv-maps into one. It also takes a long time.

[image]

To combine 4 UV maps into one map, I first jointed 4 objects into one object. Next, I clicked smart uv projection or unwrap to combine them. But it took a very long time. I would like to make one texture for the final rendering speed in paraview if it is possible. It would be good if there is a method to copy and translate UV map. Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what is your goal of baking a single texture for an entire cityscape? how are you gonna use it after?

Comment: If I could bake a single texture for the entire cityscape, I could import it faster and deal with it easily in another application Paraview. My goal is to visualize a simulated meteorological data with buildings for scientific visualization using Paraview.

Comment: You are probably better off baking few variation of buildings and use a particle system to create the cityscape. This way is more flexible too as you can apply the particle system to any ground landscape.

Comment: I don't know much about a particle system, but in my field the buildings should be used for informing of specific region with real buildings, not for just graphical background. So a virtual building data shouldn't be used.

Comment: why do you have 1700+ materials to begin with? Were they individually created? Shouldn't you have just a few, one for each building type used (linked) across the cityscape?

Comment: They were individually created and different from one another. So each buildings have their identification. So I shouldn't make the cityscape by coping just a few materials.

Comment: This is getting off topic here but is there a purpose in your simulation in having all individual buildings uniquely designed and modeled? Sorry to ask but without the full info, that seems quite overkill.

Comment: Yes, there is. The purpose is to visulize a meteorological simulation data at a local distict in mega city. So some parallel way seems to be helpful.

Comment: Hm... ok so let's try another route: you say you can bake your whole scene into 4 UV map but can't combine them, what do you mean?

Comment: To combine 4 UV maps into one map, I first jointed 4 objects into one object. Next, I clicked smart uv projection or unwrap to combine them. But it took a very long time. It would be good if there is a method to copy and translate UV map. I know that there is a plugin "magic UV", but when I copy and paste UV map to new large image, the map is stretched to the large image. I failed.

Comment: sorry I don't understand the 4 UVs process you are doing. Have you tried splitting your scene into multiple areas and bake the individual maps? For example, divide your city into neighborhoods and make each neighborhood a separate mesh with its own baked map? That should allow you to balance the processing time vs the final rendering speed.  In other words, why don't you keep your 4 objects separate in paraview?

Comment: Yes, I divided my city into 4 neighborhoods and applied smart uv projection to each mesh. But I would like to make one texture for the final rendering speed in paraview if it is possible.